# Adding month name in multiple textbox when combobox change in VBA

Tags: vba

I have one combobox with a month name list and twelve textboxes.

I want to write code that allows me to add a month name when a month name is selected in combobox.

When you select January in combobox, then the value of textbox1 will be January, textbox2 will be February and so on...

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328461/2727437

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill in a textbox based on user selection in a Combobox (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328159/how-to-fill-in-a-textbox-based-on-user-selection-in-a-combobox-vba)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. What have you tried? Please [edit] your question (do *not* add comments) and provide your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Include any error messages and stack traces.
You may want to take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question.

Comment: If I understood the question properly, it's slightly more complicated than just filling in the textbox.  The problem is to select a month and then each of the 12 textbox will display a different month, starting at the month selected.  Selecting Feb should set all of the 12 textboxes, resulting in: Textbox1=Feb, Textbox2=Mar, textbox3=Apr, ... textbox11=Dec, textbox12=Jan.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Months are in order starting at Jan in the combo box (ie. Jan index 0, Feb index 1).  Both answers use a generic date in the year 2000 with the month selected, and adds a month to it.. will loop back to Jan after Dec.

This code also assumes textboxes are in order on the form.

```
    Private Sub cboMonth_Change2()
        Dim TempDate As Date
        TempDate = "2000-" & cboMonth.ListIndex + 1 & "-01"

        Dim oControl As Control
        For Each oControl In UserForm1.Controls
            If TypeName(oControl) = "TextBox" Then
                oControl.Text = Format(TempDate, "MMMM")
                TempDate = DateAdd("M", 1, TempDate)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

This is a slightly more manual process but you can specify which textbox gets what.

```
    Private Sub cboMonth_Change()
        Dim TempDate As Date
        TempDate = "2000-" & cboMonth.ListIndex + 1 & "-01"

        TextBox1.Text = Format(DateAdd("M", 0, TempDate), "MMMM")
        TextBox2.Text = Format(DateAdd("M", 1, TempDate), "MMMM")
        TextBox3.Text = Format(DateAdd("M", 2, TempDate), "MMMM")
        ...
    End Sub
```